# Como carregar a Página e Imagem usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu já tenho o código para carregar a página em si mas a imagem das páginas ficam numa pasta diferente ai não carrega junto da página, esse é o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html>
       <head>
           
            <title>AwesomeMods</title>
    
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../CSS/Index.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../CSS/ModsPage.css">
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(function () {
                $("#aside").load("../../../Aside.html");
                $("#footer").load("../../../Footer.html");
                $("#header").load("../../../Header.html");
             });
          </script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
         
           <header id="header">      
         
         </header>
       
            <section>
                <h1 id="ModsTitle">Age of Empires Definitive Edition</h1>
                
                 
    
                <h2>Mods Graphics</h2>
                
                   <p>It is page contain all mods for this game, select your preferred mod and download.</p>
                
                <h3>Shaders</h3>
    
             <ul>  
                 <li id="shaders"><a href="PhotorealisticAgeOfEmpiresDE/PhotorealisticAgeOfEmpiresDE.html" id="download">PhotorealisticAgeOfEmpiresDE</a></li>
               
             </ul>
                      
            </section>
            
                <aside  id="aside">
             
            </aside>

            <footer id="footer">
           
            </footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Header

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
    </head>
    <body>
      <span id="foto">
            <img src="Imagens/SiteFoto.png" id="logo"> 
        </span>
    
        <nav>
            <a href="Index.html" id="menu">Home</a>
            <a href="Mods.html" id="menu">Mods</a>
            <a href="Donate.html" id="menu">Donate</a>

        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Footer

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container-594f03cb0dacb4bf20ac3ac0f313fc6f"></div>
            <div id="footerstyle">
            <ol> 
                <li><h3 id="separar">Mods Links</h3></li>                     
                <li id="links"><a href="https://reshade.me/" target="_blank" id="modlink"><img src="Imagens/Reshade Button.png" id="modlogo"> Reshade</a></li>
                <li id="links"><a href="http://enbdev.com/" target="_blank" id="modlink"><img src="Imagens/ENBSeries Button.png" id="modlogo">EnbSeries</a></li>
                <li id="links"><a href="https://www.moddb.com" title="Game Mod Development Home" target="_blank" id="modlink"><img src="https://media.moddb.com/images/global/moddb.png" alt="Mod DB - Change the Game" border="0" width="42" height="44" id="modlogo">Moddb</a></li>
                <li id="links"><a href="https://www.nexusmods.com/" target="_blank" id="modlink"><img src="Imagens/kisspng-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-nexus-mods-borderlands-5b3803b53afeb3.6385348015303976212417.png" id="modlogo">Nexus Mods</a></li>
            </ol>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcALwpmzS7rZ3w0VczM4OJw" target="_blank"> <img src="Imagens/BannerSite.png" id="banner"> </a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não use cumprimentos ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) e [mre] para poder elaborar uma boa pergunta!

Comment: Adiciona um desses htmls que são carregados via jQuery e a estrutura de pastas do projeto, que aí fica mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @FábioMiranda  Pronto, acabei de fazer isso

Comment: @DouglasLopes coloca a sintaxe assim `src="./Imagens/SiteFoto.png"` e vê se funciona.

Comment: @FábioMiranda Não funcionou

Comment: @DouglasLopes o correto ai seria uma **organização estrutural** de arquivos e pastas, para não ocorrer esses problemas.

Comment: @gleisin-dev e como devo organiza-las ???

Comment: colocar os arquivos index/paginados de acordo com o local das imagens/estilo e etc. Ex: *"imagens\minha-imagem.png"* e *"imagens\carregar-imagens.html"* e em **carregar-imagens.html** `src="minha-imagem.png"`, e assim sucessivamente..

Comment: @gleisin-dev Na verdade eu resolvi o problema passando o caminho absoluto da url do dominio todo, não sei se é melhor maneira mais funcionou.

Comment: @DouglasLopes Melhor maneira não é! Pois se for necessário uma alteração de domínio, você terá todo um trabalho para alterá-lo no código fonte (*principalmente se seu projeto for de grande porte, aíiiiii meu amigo... vai dar trabalho*)

Comment: @gleisin-dev até não, se ele deixar o caminho absoluto na base de dados basta alterar na base de dados, usa em uma variavel. Bastante fácil de dar a volta a essa questão se o projeto for grande e precisar alterar tudo.